# Javascript program unchecking checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox list and also a radiobutton control in vb.net with Yes and No responses. When the No response is selected, I'm trying to get the one checked box in the checkbox list to uncheck itself. I was able to get the textbox for "Other type" which sits next to the Other checkbox to remove the contents in the textbox. However, the Other checkbox, or any other of the checkboxes are not getting unchecked at the same time they are being disabled.  Here is the code I have presently. I tried to use the line checkboxes[i].checked=false; to uncheck the box, but the error I get is cannot set the checked property of undefined.  I don't understand how checkboxes[i] can be undefined when the previous line sees it ok and disables it. How can I get this to both disable and uncheck any checked box?

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Enableboxes1() {
            var rb = document.getElementById("<%= rbbormaraddendum.ClientID %>");
            var radio = rb.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var label = rb.getElementsByTagName("label");
            for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
                if (radio[i].checked) {
                    if (radio[i].value == "Yes") {
                        var chkList2 = document.getElementById('<%=checkboxlist1.ClientID %>');
                        var checkboxes = chkList2.getElementsByTagName("input");
                        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
                            checkboxes[i].disabled = false;
                        var tb = document.getElementById('<%=txtborothermarital.ClientID%>');
                        tb.disabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
                if (radio[i].checked) {
                    if (radio[i].value == "No") {
                        var chkList2 = document.getElementById('<%=checkboxlist1.ClientID %>');
                        var checkboxes = chkList2.getElementsByTagName("input");
                        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
                        checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
                        // HERE trying to uncheck box. The line below breaks the code
                        // checkboxes[i].checked=false;
                        var tb = document.getElementById("<%= txtborothermarital.ClientID %>");
                        tb.disabled = true;
                        tb.value = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```html
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbbormaraddendum" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onclick="Enableboxes1()">
        <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
          
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxlist1" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow" TextAlign="Right" runat="server" Enabled="false" onclick="Enableboxes1()">
            
<asp:ListItem onclick="UncheckOthers(this);" Value="CivilUnion">Civil Union</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem onclick="UncheckOthers(this);" Value="DomesticPartnership">Domestic Partnership</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem onclick="UncheckOthers(this);" Value="RegisteredPartnership">Registered Partnership</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem onclick="UncheckOthers(this);" Value="RegisteredReciprocalBeneficiaryRelationship"> Registered Reciprocal Beneficiary Relationship</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem onclick="UncheckOthers(this);" Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```